Do I need a Transit Visa in CDG
I will be transiting in Paris CDG from T2D to T2C to catch my connecting flight to India. I am an Indian passport holder with long term UK work visa. I am flying from UK to India transiting via Paris CDG as mentioned above.
Thanks,
Roy

Just to add, no checked baggage.

Are the two flights on the same ticket?

Have you read the French Goverment website Airport Transit Visa?

...UK is not in the EU, the EEA, or the Schengen area, and is not mentioned in any of the exemption categories.

You will necessarily need a visa. Which type depends on how the two tickets were booked:

If the two flights are on the same ticket, you will need an Airport Transit Visa (ATV): Indian citizens need one to transit in CDG and there is no exemption for holders of a UK visa or residence permit.
If the two flights are booked separately, the first airline will consider your final destination to be France, and will require you to have a full Schengen visa (type C), regardless of your further travel plans.

